# How to use map(lambda x) with 3 conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I map the conditions in lambda like the code below:

```
map(lambda example: {'labels': 1 if example['sentiment'] == 'positive', 
                               2 if example['sentiment'] == 'negative'
                               else 0}
```

My dataset is:

```
sentiment
positive
negative
neutral
```

OBS:  I know I can use `get_dummies` but I need to do this with map lambda, please.

Comment: "but I need to do this with map lambda, please." Not only do you not *need* to, you *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach, but if you want the code this should work

```py
map(lambda example: {'labels': 1 if example['sentiment'] == 'positive' else 
                               (2 if example['sentiment'] == 'negative' else 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a bunch of simple `if`/`else`, it is almost always an hint that you should use a `dict`:

```py
>>> labels_mapping = {"positive": 1, "negative": 2, "neutral": 0}

>>> data = ["positive", "negative", "neutral", "positive"]
>>> data_labels = list(map(lambda example: labels_mapping[example], data))
>>> data_labels
[1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Actually, you then didn't need a lambda anymore, because you can use the `__getitem__` method of the constructed `dict`:

```py
>>> list(map(labels_mapping.__getitem__, data))
[1, 2, 0, 1]
```

And to catch unexpected values (similar to the last `else` clause of the corresponding `if`/`else` statement), you can use a `defaultdict` to assign a default value:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> labels_mapping = defaultdict(lambda: -1, {"positive": 1, "negative": 2, "neutral": 0})

>>> data = ["positive", "negative", "neutral", "positive", "noise"]
>>> data_labels = list(map(labels_mapping.__getitem__, data))
>>> data_labels
[1, 2, 0, 1, -1]
```